# Getting different behavior on span text when using position

Tags: html, css

How do I get this style => 
[image: expected output]

Using `position: absolute`? If I use `position: relative`, this works! But I need the same style above with `position: absolute` only

Position => absolute

```css
.text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px white;
  line-height: 145%;
  padding: 0.2em 0.3em;
  color: white;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
  border-radius: 3px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}
```

```html
<span class="text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</span>
```

Position => relative

```css
.text {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px white;
  line-height: 145%;
  padding: 0.2em 0.3em;
  color: white;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
  border-radius: 3px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}
```

```html
<span class="text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</span>
```

Why this happens and how can I fix this? Tried to change many things but no success.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap your normal, relatively positioned, text inside a another tag and make that absolute. This will leave the text flowing normally instead of making a single block of it. Something like this:

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 15px;
}

.text {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px white;
  line-height: 145%;
  padding: 0.2em 0.3em;
  color: white;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
  border-radius: 3px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><span class="text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</span></div>
```

With HTML/CSS the solution is often more nesting.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `textarea` inside a container `div` and give `position: relative;` to the container, and `position: absolute;` to `span`, now to be sure your div default behavior which is `display: block;` will make your span flow on the extreme left so use `display: inline-block;` for your container div